# How to resolve compiler to compile c++ program?

Tags: 11.10

Whenever I try to compile a c++ program with `g++ hello.cpp`, I get:

```
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Then if I run `sudo apt-get install g++` it outputs:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

[To fix 'held broken packages' error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1669162):

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```